# VS2015 WPF Designer Failed to load FileLoadException HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, visual-studio-2015, designer

I am creating a WPF project in VS2015, every thing works, even app compiles and runs successfully, but I couldn't load the designer. I am getting the following Exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction, Version=4.3.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.AppDomainFactory.AddBindingRedirectForAssembly(String assemblyName, String publicKeyToken, String oldVersion, String newVersion)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.AppDomainFactory.ConfigureMandatoryAssemblies()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.AppDomainFactory.ConfigureAppDomain()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.AppDomainFactory.CreateAppDomainInfo()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.b__0()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Anything else is working fine, just the designer isn't loading up.

Comment: It is a VS assembly, stored in the common7\ide\publicassemblies directory.  This shouldn't go wrong of course.  Check if the drive is still healthy and do the repair/reinstall dance.

Comment: May be this will help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4d678222-9c85-4346-b2bf-ae85f6f3ebca/systemiofileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftwindowsdesigninteraction?forum=vssetup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So Re-installing VS2015 with Standard Settings did the job for me. Everything is working fine now.

Cause of issue:
I had previously installed VS with custom options and only Web tools selected. That's why few packages were missing. So re-installing with Standard settings did the work.